# Computer all possible pairs oft two lists efficiency

Tags: time-complexity

Let's say I have two sets of numbers and I want to build all pairs oft the values inside oft it. For example:

```
A = {1, 2}
B = {3, 4}
Out = {(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)}
```

My sets have a lookup time in O(1). It should be possible to compute my output in O(|A| + |B|) also if the sets do not have the same size but I don't find any solution for this [easy solution would be two foor loops but this in O(n^2)]. Can you please give me a hint how I can compute this in the given complexity?

Comment: "It should be possible to compute my output in O(|A| + |B|)":  when the size of the output is O(|A|*|B|)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do it better than two for loops.  Think about this way.  For every element in A you have to output  B elements.  So you running time will always be some multiple of A*B.

Let's modify your example above for A to have 3 elements

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
B = {3, 4}
Out = {(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), {3,3}, {3,4}}
```

So you have 6 elements of output with initial sets |A| = 3 and |B| = 2.   You claim your output should be |A| + |B| which is 5.  Therefore you initial assumption is not true.

Your best optimization would be to make sure you can enumerate element of the sets in O(1) time per element.